# Constructing std::function from extern functions gives std::bad_function_call

Tags: c++, std-function, linkage

I am experimenting with making pure Haskell-style I/O in C++. It's working correctly, but when I reorganize some definitions, I run into a `std::bad_function_call`.

This is about as much as it takes to trigger the problem:

```cpp
//common.h

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

class Empty {};
class State {};

template <class A>
class IOMonad {
public:
  typedef std::function<std::pair<A, State> (State)> T;
};

template <class A, class B>
const auto bind(typename IOMonad<A>::T ma, std::function<typename IOMonad<B>::T (A)> f) {
  return [ma, f] (State state) {
    const auto x = ma(state);
    return f(x.first)(x.second);
  };
}

extern const IOMonad<std::string>::T getLine;
IOMonad<Empty>::T putLine(std::string str);
```

```cpp
//externs.cpp

#include "common.h"

const IOMonad<std::string>::T getLine = [](State s) {
  (void)s;
  std::string str;
  std::cin >> str;
  return std::make_pair(str, State());
};

IOMonad<Empty>::T putLine(std::string str) {
  return [str] (State s) {
    (void)s;
    std::cout << str;
    return std::make_pair(Empty(), State());
  };
}
```

```cpp
//main.cpp

#include "common.h"

const auto putGet = bind<std::string, Empty>(getLine, putLine);

int main() {
  (void)putGet(State());
  return 0;
}
```

With this setup, I get a `std::bad_function_call` when `putGet` is called. Previously, I had the contents of `externs.cpp` in `main.cpp` between including `common.h` and defining `putGet`, and everything worked fine. Something about having those functions in a different translation unit seems to be causing this problem. Also, if I keep the functions in `externs.cpp`, but I make `putGet` a local variable to `main` instead of a global variable, this does not happen. Another thing that makes the exception go away is folding the definition of `bind` into the definition of `putGet`, like so:

```cpp
const auto putGet = [] (State state) {
  const auto x = getLine(state);
  return putLine(x.first)(x.second);
};
```

Why is this happening? Does `std::function` have some limitations I don't know about?

Comment: Seems like static initialization order fiasco. `putGet` is likely initialized before `getLine`. Put `putGet` into `main()` for test, maybe have `make_getLine` or a simple function.

Comment: https://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/static-init-order.html

Comment: Make `getLine` an actual function instead of a `std::function` holding a lambda.  Objects and functions are fundamentally different in C++, and have different rules governing lifetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've run afoul of the static initialization order fiasco.  In your case, `getLine` is yet uninitialized when it's used to initialize `putGet`.

The cardinal rule of C++ global variables is: **Global variables must not depend on global variables in other compilation units for their initialization**.

While global variables in a single compilation unit are initialized in the order they're defined, the order in which global variables in different compilation units are initialized is unspecified.  There is no guarantee that `getLine` will be initialized before `putGet` (and indeed, it seems it wasn't).

To work around this, you need to either (two of which you've already found):

A. Move the initialization of `putGet` into `main` so that `getLine` is guaranteed to be initialized before it's used

or

B. Don't use `getLine` directly in the initialization of `putGet` (i.e. wrap it in an extra layer of lambda).

or

C. Make `getLine` an actual function instead of a `std::function` holding a lambda.  Objects and functions are fundamentally different in C++ and have different rules governing their lifetime.  Despite their name, `std::function`s are objects, not functions.